# Strategy to pass data from included PHP file

Tags: php, oop

The following code presents a way that I am currently rendering my pages through `index.php`. The problem is that I'm not sure how to re-think this so I can pass a page title before the template has been included.

How other way I could do this? This is just my index page, please ask if more code needed.

`include($cms->GetTheme() . "/head.php");` This should get the Title information before being included, but I'm not sure how to pass data there from later included page.

```
include('config/config.inc.php');

$cms = new cms();

if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && !empty($_GET['page'])) {
    include($cms->GetTheme() . "/head.php");
    $cms->IncludeModule($_GET['page']); <- actual page being included
    include($cms->GetTheme() . "/foot.php");
} // end (GET || POST) && GET
else { // just index.php
    include($cms->GetTheme() . "/head.php");
    foreach($cms->GetModuleList() as $module) {
        echo " <a href=\"index.php?page=$module\"> $module </a><br />";
    }
    include($cms->GetTheme() . "/foot.php");
} // end ELSE
```

Example page being included. `The $this->SetTitle($module_name);` I would use to set the page title.

```
<?php
    $module_name        = 'Log out user';
    $module_directory   = 'admin';
    $this->SetTitle($module_name); // setting page title

    if(count(get_required_files()) < 2) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
            $this->DestroyUser();

            echo "You have been logged out! Please navigate to the <a href=\"index.php?page=login\">Login Page</a>.";
        }
        else {
            header('Location: index.php?page=login'); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Short of a nasty output buffering hack, you cant. Normal practice is to separate logic and presentation, so all your data is defined before any output is made to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are echos all over the place. Try and limit the places where you do that by storing the output, rather than printing it all out straight away.

In your module for example, you could do `$this->content = "You have been logged out..."`

Then you can change the order of execution:

```
$cms->IncludeModule($_GET['page']);
include($cms->GetTheme() . "/head.php");
echo $cms->content;    
include($cms->GetTheme() . "/foot.php");
```

Comment: I think that's a good idea. Also will save some coding in the future.